# Spoof client user agent in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a route that redirects iPhones, but no great way to test it:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req }) => {
  const isIphone = req.headers['user-agent'].match(/iPhone/i);

  if (isIphone) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        ...
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {}
  };
}
```

Is there some way one can spoof the user agent head client side? It seems that changing the `navigator.userAgent` property does not suffice for whatever `fetch` function next.js is using under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is this a question about browser tasing? If So - Safari > Develop >
   Enter Responsive Design Mode > Dropdown
2. Use an iPhone emulator.

Hopefully you are not accessing using any intermediaries who add headers.

Comment: In addition to this, one can use Safari's Develop > User Agent function to spoof a UA such that the next server's SSR handlers receive said UA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use their `userAgent` helper:

```js
import { userAgent } from 'next/server';

// ...
const isMobile = userAgent(req).device.type === 'mobile'
```